# No user is able to login to our SharePoint 2013 portal

Tags: 2013, access, adfs

We have a properly working SP2013 with ADFS environment on Amazon(EC2). We are using PING Fedrate as our SAML Token Provider. Everything was working fine till yesterday. Every user started getting following error,
[image]

The event logs on the ADFS server shows, Event ID 364 with following details,

> Encountered error during federation passive request.
>
> Exception details:
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.UnsupportedSamlResponseException:
>   MSIS7029: The SAML response has content that is not supported.    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.BuildSignInResponseForProtocolResponse(FederationPassiveContext
>   federationPassiveContext)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveAuthentication.BuildSignInResponse(SecurityToken
>   securityToken)

No patching was done on servers.
No new known installations were done.
Nothing known seems to change.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you see any error in the SharePoint logs as well? try IIS reset on the SharePoint server, also reset the browser cache

Comment: Try to make backup and remove hotfixes KB2843638 and KB2843639, like described here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/windowsserver/en-US/cb15677d-a7f5-4b47-84ae-1826252bb4ae/adfs-error-364-111-after-windows-update-kb2843639

Comment: Thanks Waqas and Gennady. We got it resolved. I will post the details as answer. So that it may help somebody in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, on our domain controller, the time was 10 min. ahead of the actual time. When it was corrected the users were able to enter normally.

We are assuming that the time difference was interfering with the encryption/decryption of the SAML token and hence the error says `The SAML response has content that is not supported`.